# What makes this specific implementation of Insertionsort so much faster than others?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, runtime

I have implemented three different versions of Insertionsort in Python. After timing how long each on takes to sort a large list, I noticed how the third one is much faster than the others. Why is that? Aren't they all essentially doing the same and have the same time complexity of O(n^2)?

```
def insertionsort1(array):

    n = len(array)

    for i in range(n):

        index = 0
        while array[i] > array[index]:
            index +=1

        element = array.pop(i)
        array[index:index] = [element]

    return array


def insertionsort2(arr):

    n = len(arr)

    for i in range(1, n):

        for j in range(i):

            if arr[i] <= arr[j]:

                cache = arr.pop(i)
                arr[j:j] = [cache]

    return arr

def insertionsort3(arr):

    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n-1):
        pos = i+1

        while pos > 0 and arr[pos] < arr[pos-1]:
            arr[pos], arr[pos-1] = arr[pos-1], arr[pos]
            pos -= 1
    return arr

def timeit(func, arr, n_runs):
    times = []
    for i in range(n_runs):
        start = time.time()
        _ = func(arr)
        end = time.time()
        times.append(end - start)
    avg_time = sum(times) / len(times)
    print(f'Function finished in {round(avg_time, 4)} second(s)')

array = list(np.random.randint(1, 10000, size=10000))

timeit(insertionsort1, array, 1)
timeit(insertionsort2, array, 1)
timeit(insertionsort3, array, 1)
```

Output of the program:

Function finished in 2.2218 second(s)

Function finished in 3.4489 second(s)

Function finished in 0.0 second(s)

Comment: If you use a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile), you will see that `pop` is the culprit. Swaping elements is much quicker than popping and inserting.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Nah, that's not it.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Also, that popping+inserting is **faster** than all those swaps.

Answer (score 4):

You are sorting **already sorted** array.

In this case insertion sort takes linear time, so works very fast (it is so-called [adaptive sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort)).

If you put call `timeit(insertionsort3, array, 1)` at the first place, you'll see close time for `insertionsort3`

Note that there are too much exchanges in the third function, nevertheless it is close to canonic implementation (while exploiting Python specific might give some gain for other variants)

```
   for i in range(n-1):
        pos = i+1
        t = arr[pos]
        while pos > 0 and t < arr[pos-1]:
            arr[pos] = arr[pos-1]
            pos -= 1
        arr[pos] = t
```

Comment: I forgot about the side effects. Now it seems like Insertionsort3 is actually the slowest out of them. Your improvement is also faster.

Comment: Python specific  - in the most of compiled languages 1st variant with element popping and inserting should be slower than element shifting from the 3rd variant, but here inserting is in-built routine implemented in C, and is faster.